# Find the value of p for which the integral converges and evaluate integral for $\int ^\infty_e \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Find the value of p for which the integral converges and evaluate  integral for $\int ^\infty_e \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx$

MY ATTEMPT: Given Integral:
 $I= \int ^\infty_e \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx$

put $\ln x =t\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}dx=dt$ and $x\rightarrow \infty,t\rightarrow \infty, x=e, t\rightarrow 1$

$\therefore I= \int ^\infty_e \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx=\int^\infty_1 \frac{1}{t^p} dt$

Hence the integral is convergent for p>1..
how to find the value of integral for those values of p

Comment: Just evaluate it using the power rule

Comment: @ZacharySelk ..sorry how to evaluate i dont have idea of power rule

Comment: Then how did you know the integral is convergent? This is a very routine integral, probably the very first integral you encounter!

Comment: @sorry..i just wrong ...fine..i have dought we can directly apply integration

Comment: Hint: the power rule for differentiation is $\frac{d}{dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$. Can you invert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $u= \ln x$ we get $du = \frac{1}{x} \, dx$. We have

$$\int ^\infty_e \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx = \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{u^p}\, du = \lim_{a \to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{1-p}u^{1-p} \right]_1^a, \, \text{for } p \neq 1.$$

Now consider the cases $1 - p > 0$ and $1 - p < 0$. Lastly, consider the case where $p=1$ which will involve a new antiderivative.

Comment: i got it thanks..